# remove integer index an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am working on a website where we need to remove the index of an array where type is integer.
Have you any idea or suggestion regarding.
My array looks like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => first
    [first] => second
    [1] => second
    [second] => second
    [2] => third
    [third] => third
    [3] => forth
    [forth] => v
    [4] => fifth
    [fifth] => fifth
)
```

How we can remove integer index from array.One more thing to note that we have not static array we do not know how many index is there.

Need like this :

```
Array
(  
    [first] => second  
    [second] => second  
    [third] => third  
    [forth] => v
    [fifth] => fifth
)
```

Comment: do you get this from database? if so then which? if this is mysql use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: Ok but have you any idea how to remove integer index.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Database Solution:**

To get only the associative array from mysql database use: [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead of [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

`mysqli_fetch_array()` fetches the entire array - integer indexes as well as column names as keys.

`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` only fetches the column names as keys. - thus getting rid of integer keys.

---

**General Solution:**

To do what you asked in general I would use:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(is_numeric($key)) unset($array[$key]);
}
```

You can also use `is_int()` if you like..

Comment: I mean if array is not coming from database.What we can do for the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this :-

```
$array1 = array("6566"=>"zd  xf", "2"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
$keys=array_filter(array_keys($array1), "is_numeric");
$out =array_diff_key($array1,array_flip($keys));
print_r($out);
```

output :

```
Array
(
[c] => 3

[d] => 4

[e] => 5

)
```

Comment: I dont see the need to create a function... You can write the same thing just with no function like this:

$array1 = array("6566"=>"zd  xf", "2"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
$keys=array_filter(array_keys($array1), "is_numeric");
$out =array_diff_key($array1,array_flip($keys));
print_r($out);

Comment: @gabrielem thanks (that call back native function "is_numeric").

Answer (score 3):

remove the integer index value of array.

```
$array1=array();
$array = array(0 => first,first => second,1 => second,second => second,2 => third,third => third,3 => forth,forth => v,4 => fifth,fifth => fifth);
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
    if(gettype($key)=='integer'){
       unset($key);
       unset($value);
   }else{
    $array1[$key]=$value;
  }
}
print_r($array1);
```

out put like this.

```
Array
```

(
    [first] => second
    [second] => second
    [third] => third
    [forth] => v
    [fifth] => fifth
)